# Validation on Form Drop-down using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some validation that I have built out for my form, but I can't get the drop-down to work on the validation portion. Does anyone have some ideas?

The email portion validates and the submit buttons prevents the form from being submitted until the validation is good.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7HzH.png)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[name=requestType]').click(function() {
    if (this.value == 'Single User') {
      $(".groupName").hide();
      $(".totalUsers").hide();
      $("#both1").hide();
    } else {
      $(".groupName").show();
      $(".totalUsers").show();
      $("#both1").show();
    }
  });

  $("#submit").click(function() {
    if (validate()) {
      AddListItem();
      return false;
    } else {
    }
  });
});

function validateEmail(email) {
  var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  return re.test(email);
}

function validate() {
  var valid = false;
  var $result = $("#result");
  var email = $("#requesterEmail").val();
  $result.text("");

  if (validateEmail(email)) {
    $result.text("This email address is valid.");
    $result.css("color", "green");
    valid = true;
  } else {
    $result.text("Please provide a valid email address.");
    $result.css("color", "red");
  }
  return valid;
}

function getItem() {

  var item = {
    Title: $("#requesterEmail").val(),
    TeamName: $("#groupName").val(),
    NumberOfAttendees: $("#totalUsers").val(),
    RequestType: $("input[name=requestType]:checked").val(),
    SessionType: $('#rChoices :selected').text(),
    ComputerType: $("input[name=computerType]:checked").val()
  };
  return item;
}

function AddListItem(resources) {

  var item = getItem();

  $pnp.setup({
    baseUrl: "/Training/"
  });

  $pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Training").items.add(item).then(function(r) {
    $("#submit").hide();
    $(".form").hide();
    $("#divider").hide();
    $(".submitHide").hide();
    $("#mText").hide();
    $("#header").hide();
    $("#test").hide();
    $("#DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea").hide();
    $("#hidden_div").show();
    $("#cancel").hide();
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group row rChoices">
  <label for="rChoices" class="col-form-label">Please choose a application below:</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="rChoices" onchange="videoSelect(this.value)">
    <option class="" selected disabled>---------</option>
    <option value="onedrive" id="onedrive" onclick="videoSelect(this.value)">OneDrive</option>
    <option value="teams" id="teams" onclick="videoSelect(this.value)">Teams</option>
    <option value="outlook" id="outlook" onclick="videoSelect(this.value)">Outlook</option>
    <option value="officesuite" id="officesuite" onclick="videoSelect(this.value)">Office Suite</option>
    <option value="planner" id="planner" onclick="videoSelect(this.value)">Planner</option>
    <option value="sharepoint" id="sharepoint" onclick="videoSelect(this.value)">SharePoint</option>
    <option value="stream" id="stream" onclick="videoSelect(this.value)">Stream</option>
    <option value="yammer" id="yammer" onclick="videoSelect(this.value)">Yammer</option>
  </select>
  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
</div>
```

Would really appreciate all the help that I can get on this.

Comment: I would suggest using something like parsley.js to take the hassle out of form validation. It doesn't look like you are performing any validation on your select though.

Comment: Whatever client-side validation you do, you will still have to do server-side validation, so if it is not important, than do not spend much time on it.

Comment: One observation, no where do you have a function called `videoSelect` but you refer to it in your HTML. Nor do you have any validation whatsoever on the select.

Comment: @dahliacreative, thanks so much! I didn't know about parsley.js.

Comment: @Graphicdev no worries.